# Laravel URL Rewrite

Tags: php, url-rewriting, laravel

To go directly to the controller on my laravel access by accessing :

```
http://localhost/laravel/public/home
```

Do i have to dont use **/public** ?
Can I just use :

```
http://localhost/laravel/home
```

Is this because the directory is on the public folder that causes this and should be like this?

Thanks

Comment: There are many ways to to that, depending on your current setup, as Sébastien said. Did you check the 'Server Configuration' part on http://laravel.com/docs/install, also this is a good resource on the official forums: http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=1258

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends where your instance of Laravel is located, and whether rewrite rules have been set.

Assuming your Apache/nginx document root is /my/dir/ and your public folder is /my/dir/public/ (which makes the Laravel directory /my/dir/laravel/), you will need the /public/.

However, if your root dir is /my/dir/ and your laravel folder is in /my/laravel/, you can rename public to dir and skip using the public part, as it is now mapped to the documentRoot for the webserver.

You can change all the paths in multiple places:

- The locations of the `paths.php` file (which defines all the other paths) is in `index.php` in your public folder
- The location of all the other paths is defined in `paths.php`, one by one. The public one is $paths["public"]. You can change this to anything you like and it will impact both Laravel and the Artisan CLI interface. Bear in mind that Laravel does a small directory transformation after the variable is set (still in that file).

Comment: Then why don't you accept the answer, and/or tell us how you solved your problem :)